# Blockchain: CA service and fault tolerance

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am moving my first steps in the amazing world of Blockchains. This technology have a lot of very interesting aspects I am interested to understand.

To make it short, a Blockchain represents a distributed and decentralized database deployed on a peer-to-peer network. Nodes are equally privileged, and equipotent participants: for each of them a full replica of the dataset is made available. This design assure a very high degree of fault tolerance (Byzantine) and can enable data integrity through proper cryptography and a consensus algorithm.

I was now looking at a chainbase implementation based on Hyperledger Fabric, a blockchain framework implementation hosted by The Linux Foundation.
In particular, I came through an amazing sample project called **Hyperledger Fabric Basics** published by Anna D Derbakova and available on GitHub at: https://github.com/angrbrd/hyperledger-fabric-basics.
In this implementation, the author defined a network made of:

- 4 peers;
- 1 master service node CA.

[image: blockchain network]

Please, correct me if I am wrong, but does the master service node represent a single point of failure for the whole implementation? Indeed, the blockchain will be shared between the peers. However without a CA, it should not be possible anymore issuing signing keys for new transactions.
If true, which approaches are typically used to achieve a more robust design for a blockchain implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cited work is rather dated, and based on an older architecture that is no longer relevant. Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 was recently released and is not dependent on a single CA as the previous architecture required. Please see [How to avoid the Fabric CA beeing a single point of failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309100/how-to-avoid-the-fabric-ca-beeing-a-single-point-of-failure/45309597#45309597) for more on this subject.

Comment: My bad, I did see this topic. Thanks

Comment: no worries, mate, the SPoF was recognized back then and we took explicit steps to remediate with the current design.